# Using entities from parent function

Tags: lisp

Usually it is obvious to use the entities of the parent function by any function called within parent function.
IF I have,

```
(defun fun1(x)(let ((y nil))(fun2)))

(defun fun2 () (print y)))
```

then (fun1 2) complains about y. How do I use entities from a parent function into child function, say fun2 able to access entities of let scope of f1.

Comment: In your code it's unpossible to access `Y` from `fun1` from `fun1` `let` scope anyway, because you'r passing `Y` as argument to `fun2`.

Comment: You failed to indent/format your code properly. I did it for you. I don't know what a 'parent function' is, what the parent function in your example is and why it is 'obvious' to use something from a so-called 'parent function'. In your example there is no scope where *x* should be available to *fun2*.

Comment: `fun1('(a b c))` is not valid in Lisp. Are you sure this is a Lisp-question?

Comment: I am sorry for making mistake and not checking it twice. I hope its more clear now.

Comment: @RainerJoswig: I use a tool written over lisp and I jumbled the syntax here. Sorry my bad.

Comment: @Rorschach: why don't you indent and format your functions properly?

Comment: @RainerJoswig: *pretty-print* is giving similar output, so I didn't make any change.

Comment: @Rorschach: That can't be the case. *pretty print* prints correct Lisp code. **Your code is wrong.** You might want to format and indent your code correctly. Then try it. Then you also might find the error. A Lisp compiler says: `caught ERROR ... compilation aborted`. So. please check your code, run it, correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You descritption and code is really wrong, but I'll answer you up to my understanding what you want to do.

To do such thing you need to `declare` your variable as `special`:

```
(defun parent-fun (x)
  (let ((y nil))
    (declare (special y))
    (child-fun x)))

(defun child-fun (x)
  (declare (special y)) ;; Without this declatation it'll work
  `(,x ,y))             ;; but you'll get a warning


CL-USER> (parent-fun '(a b c))
((A B C) NIL)
```

Comment: @Rorschach then you should probably accept the answer.